# What technology does HTML5 email input type use?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, email-validation

**Question 1:** 
I saw `email input type` in HTML5,
works even if I disable my Javascript in Browser, Then what technology does it use to validate?

**Question 2:**
Also, In the firebug `profiler`, I saw `data-val-regex` of ASP.NET , inturn calls `Jquery`, how the control is transferred to that ? That is `data-val-regex` is JQuery's feature or HTML's feature?

Reference :

```
<div style="width:255px; height: 30px; float:left;"><input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please&#32;enter&#32;valid&#32;email&#32;id" data-val-regex-pattern=".+\@.+\..+" />
```

Answer (score 3):

**Answer 1**: This is a browser feature. Some browsers can read the `type` property of the input and behave accordingly. For example an iPad will show the numeric keypad for `number` input and a special keyboard which has the @ sign for the `email` input.

**Answer 2**: This is a feature of the unobtrusive libraries from Microsoft. Basically those attributes (all beginning with `data-`) are HTML5 valid attributes and are harvested when the page is displayed, then bridged over to the jquery validate by creating rules and methods. For a better explanation, you can have a look at one of my old [answers on how to roll your own validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790320/client-side-validation-of-a-timespan-on-asp-net-mvc-3/10790794#10790794) and will hopefully make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`Data-` is a custom attribute in HTML5 spec

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.
>
> These attributes are not intended for use by software that is
>   independent of the site that  uses the attributes.
>
> Every HTML element may have any number of custom data attributes
>   specified, with any value.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

If you want to know more info
http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/